# Set Up Data Endpoint to Receive Pushed Data from API

Tags: ajax, rest, api

I have a third party provider who has an API operating in PUSH mode sending data to my site, I created a .htpasswd protected empty directory on the root of my site and sent them the credentials hoping that I could use this as an endpoint. They say they are sending json POST method payloads and getting a success response but I have not been able to see any data and I'm  unsure how to capture it so I can save it.

I am used to working with APIs wher I send a POST or GET request but in this case they are sending the data to me so it's new territory.

I have tried getJSON, I attempted .fetch and XMLHttpRequest but I haven't had any joy so I wonder if I am capable of receiving these payload to this endpoint at all?

I think I need to build a basic API on my end capable of receiving POST requests but not sure where to start as when I am googling API in PUSH mode I am getting multiple pages about PUSH API which is a different thing entirely.

Comment: Yes you need to build a basic API. Pick a programming language and build a minimal thing that can accept POST requests. I don't think the term 'push' is relevant here, I think it's just meant to imply that the third party provider initiates the message, but doesn't refer to a specific tech

Comment: I emailed back and forth with the client and thought as much just whilst sounding like a clueless idiot. Going to try build something in PHP. You're right the term push didn't help. Thanks for your reply.